# How to observe changes in sub properties of an observable array?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Service I have an Array as Observable:

`public conversations: Observable<Conversation[]>;`

One Conversation has an array of messages. I want to have an observable, which streams incoming messages in all Conversations. How can this be done?

Comment: use a `Subject` or `BehaviourSubject` instead of `Observable` to `emit` messages

Comment: Why would you not have `public conversation$: Observable<Conversation>[]; `instead?

Comment: oh yeah, that's a point @ritaj

Comment: I guess that solves your problem. Otherwise you would need to remember all the array elements and find the difference on each Observable emittion.